# stringr: find rows where any column content matches a regex

Tags: r, regex, stringr

Consider the following example

```
> data_text <- data.frame(text = c('where', 'are', 'you'),
                        blob = c('little', 'nice', 'text'))
> data_text
# A tibble: 3 x 2
   text   blob
  <chr>  <chr>
1 where little
2   are   nice
3   you   text
```

I want to print the rows that contain the regex `text` (that is, row 3)

Problem is, I have hundreds of columns and I dont know which one contains this string. `str_detect` only work with one column at a time...

How can I do that using the `stringr` package?
Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With `stringr` and `dplyr` you can do this.

You should use `filter_all` from `dplyr >= 0.5.0`.

I have extended the data to have a better look on the result:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

data_text <- data.frame(text = c('text', 'where', 'are', 'you'),
                    one_more_text = c('test', 'test', 'test', 'test'),
                    blob = c('wow', 'little', 'nice', 'text'))

data_text %>%
  filter_all(any_vars(str_detect(., 'text')))

# output
  text one_more_text blob
1 text          test  wow
2  you          test text
```

Comment: Thanks!!You saved my time. Btw,what is the meaning of `.,`?

Comment: @wasmetqall It's not a `.,`, it's a dot `.` - which is a special `dplyr` specifier for "all columns". And comma is just a separator.

Comment: When I try this solution I get: Error: C stack usage is too close to the limit

Answer (score 5):

You can treat the data.frame as a list and use `purrr::map` to check each column, which can then be `reduce`d into a logical vector that `filter` can handle. Alternatively, `purrr::pmap` can iterate over all the columns in parallel:

```r
library(tidyverse)

data_text <- data_frame(text = c('where', 'are', 'you'),
                        blob = c('little', 'nice', 'text'))

data_text %>% filter(map(., ~.x == 'text') %>% reduce(`|`))
#> # A tibble: 1 x 2
#>    text  blob
#>   <chr> <chr>
#> 1   you  text

data_text %>% filter(pmap_lgl(., ~any(c(...) == 'text')))
#> # A tibble: 1 x 2
#>    text  blob
#>   <chr> <chr>
#> 1   you  text
```

Answer (score 4):

```
matches = apply(data_text,1,function(x) sum(grepl("text",x)))>0
result = data_text[matches,]
```

No other packages required. Hope this helps!

Comment: knowing base R always a plus